# How do I switch page styles with scrpage2?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I want to use two different footers with `scrpage2`: one with no `\pagemark` (page number) on the first page; and then one that includes a `\pagemark` on all following pages. How do I perform the switch between the two page styles? What I have below renders the first page footer correctly, but the rest are blank. I feel like this is more a general LaTeX header question than KOMA, as I found the KOMA documentation unclear on this question.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl}

%%% Load metadata

\usepackage{myinfo} % \myauthor, \mytitle, and others come from here

%%% Select typefaces

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont [Ligatures={Common},Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Inconsolata}

%%% Define header and footer with scrpage2

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\scshape}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot[\MakeLowercase{\myauthor · Curriculum Vitae} · \pagemark]{\MakeLowercase{Curriculum Vitae · Last updated \today}}

%%% Define section headings

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\sffamily} 
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}

%%% Custom hanging indent for items in C.V.

\newenvironment{cvdatum}
    {\noindent\par\leftskip=1em \parindent=-\leftskip}
    {\par}

%%% Define PDF metadata

\usepackage[xetex, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, pdftitle={\myauthor’s \mytitle}, pdfauthor={\myauthor}]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{scrheadings}

\section*{Education}

\begin{cvdatum}
   blah
\end{cvdatum}

\section*{Publications}

\begin{cvdatum}
  blah
\end{cvdatum}

\pagestyle{plain}

\section*{Works in progress}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page style controlled by the optional argument of `\ofoot` & friends is called `scrplain`, not `plain`. Set `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` for the whole document (in the preamble or immediately after `\begin{document}`) and set `\thispagestyle{scrplain}` immediately after `\begin{document}`. (Note: I switched argument contents in `\ofoot`.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\scshape}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot[\MakeLowercase{Curriculum Vitae · Last updated \today}]
    {\MakeLowercase{(Author) · Curriculum Vitae} · \pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{scrplain}

\section*{Education}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section*{Publications}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section*{Works in progress}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's it! Or rather the other way around (`\pagestyle{scrplain}` in preamble, `\thispagestyle{scrheadings}` in document). Thanks for correcting the oversight and illuminating how the switch is articulated.